# Why is there a frown icon on the screen when I re-boot my Rpi 2 with Windows IoT

Tags: pi-2, boot-issues, windows-iot, update, rpi-update

So, when I boot my RPi-2 which is running Windows IoT, the computer screen displays 2 gears and a progress bar.  Earlier, the progress bar made it all the way to completion and the RPi-2 rebooted.  However, on reboot, it went back to the two rotating gears and the progress bar.  Then, after just a few seconds, a frowny face icon was displayed :-(  Then the RPi-2 seems to shut down and the green light blinks 7 times and pauses and repeats the blinks.

Was it a failed update?  Do I need to just wipe the Micro SD card and reload Iot onto it again?  Or is there some other way to deal with this problem?

Comment: I just wiped my Micro-SD card and re-installed Windows IoT on it and things are back to normal.. Other than having to rename the Pi, reset the p@ssw0rd and get it hooked up to my wireless network.  It would be nice if there was another solution to this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/iot/2016/01/11/announcing-the-windows-10-iot-core-update/) the gear icons mean that an update is being installed. The post shows the gear icons and explains "The following image will be displayed on-screen when the update begins". I'm guessing the frown icon is displayed because there is "something wrong". I'm assuming something corrupted the SD card while updating, as your issue seemed to disappear when reinstalling.

I had the gear icons happen too; my Raspberry Pi 3B rebooted randomly while I was developing an app on my desktop. It took about 30 minutes for the progress bar to fill in and complete. After that my device rebooted about 5 times and then started normally again. However, I'm not sure my device even got updated as I can't find an update log or anything. A side effect is that it retained information such as its name, but it changed the password of the device back to the default: `p@ssw0rd`

The resources I'm finding about the sad face stem from the Nokia Lumia phones so I'm not sure how these could apply to our Raspberries.